# Lights Not Affecting Scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting

I'm new at lighting and texturing, so I've likely done something catastrophically stupid.

Got a relatively simple scene, a hockey puck slides along the ice. Started trying to add some volumetric lighting only to find that none of the textures are receiving light. When I turn Ambient Occlusion on, they all show up at full value. Ambient Occlusion off, everything goes dark.

I'm hoping this is as easy as I've accidentally touched a setting I wasn't supposed to or linked a node incorrectly, but I've uploaded the .blend since I have no clue where to begin with cause/effect on this.

[image]

Any help you can offer this despondent n00b would be appreciated.

- Blender 2.79b
- Cycles Renderer
- using the Filmic Blender color management add-on, but I've found
  no indication that it's the culprit.

EDIT 08/15/2018: I've discovered a new development. Objects with emission shaders WILL affect scene lighting, but specifically not lamps.

Answer (score 1):

You were only displaying the first layer in your viewport. Make sure to highlight both layers when previewing.

[image: Highlight both with the Shift key]

Comment: Interesting. I didn't even realize those lights had ended up on that layer. Much obliged.